# Binding initial value to material ui select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui in my react application.
And I am using select component.
I want to bind some initial values to the select control.
I had tried with the useState hook. It's not working.
Below is the code i am using.

```
const userContributors=[{
  firstName: "user101",
  id: "1",
  role: "Users"
},{
  firstName: "user102",
  id: "2",
  role: "Users"
},{
  firstName: "user103",
  id: "3",
  role: "Users"
}]

const [ApplicationAdminUsers, SetApplicationAdminUsers] = useState([
{
  firstName: "user101",
  id: "1",
  role: "Users"
}
]);

<FormControl
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true
                }}
                validators={["required"]}
                errorMessages={["Select Application Admin"]}
                className={[
                  classes.formControl,
                  "fullWidthControl",
                  "multiselect-checkbox"
                ].join(" ")}
              >
                <InputLabel
                  ref={inputLabel}
                  htmlFor="select-multiple-checkbox"
                  className="multi-label-top"
                >
                  Select Users...
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  multiple
                  value={ApplicationAdminUsers}
                  onChange={handleChangeUserContributores}
                  className="multi-input-padding"
                  validators={["required"]}
                  errorMessages={["Select Application Admin"]}
                  input={
                    <OutlinedInput
                      labelWidth={labelWidth}
                      id="select-multiple-checkbox"
                    />
                  }
                  MenuProps={MenuProps}
                >
                  {userContributors.map((item, index) => (
                    <MenuItem key={"aa" + item.id} value={item}>
                      {item.firstName}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
```

And here I'm using this as multi select control.
Any solutions to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the whole functional component's code and define more how it is not working?

Comment: Hai. Tried this in sandbox. Attaching the link. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-u1h7k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using object as material-ui Select value, you need to provide 'renderValue' prop:

```
  renderValue={selected => selected.map(item => item.firstName).join(', ')}
```

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-no3cf?fontsize=14) example

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. it works. But when i tried to click on the already selected option, it's getting added multiple times.

Comment: that happened to user1, because he was hard coded in the initial state. if you set the initial state to [userContributors[0]], it will work fine. you can check the updated CodeSandbox in my answer

Comment: it works. but i may need to bind multiple items selected based on id. not by index

Comment: how are you going to get the id's? as array? like ['1', '2', '3'] ?

Comment: no. it will be a collection. Like below [
  {
    firstName: "user101",
    id: "1",
    role: "Users"
  },
  {
    firstName: "user103",
    id: "3",
    role: "Users"
  }
]

Comment: You need to create a function, which filters UserContributors based on your initial state collection. You can check the updated CodeSandbox for example

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an object as the value for the input, it needs to be a string.

Also you haven't handled the onChange to update the array to add/remove items.

As a simple example.

```
const userContributors=["joe", "bob", "tim"]

...

const [ApplicationAdminUsers, SetApplicationAdminUsers] = useState(["joe"]);

...

<Select
 multiple
 value={ApplicationAdminUsers}
 onChange={(event)=> SetApplicationAdminUsers(event.target.value)}  
 className="multi-input-padding"
 validators={["required"]}
 errorMessages={["Select Application Admin"]}
 input={
   <OutlinedInput
      labelWidth={labelWidth}
      id="select-multiple-checkbox"
    />
  }
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
```

Comment: Hai.. thanks for your reply. But in my case i need to pass the selected id,name and role. So i have to use object right?

Comment: You could use an object and iterate over the array to just get the name strings....

```
const [ApplicationAdminUsers, SetApplicationAdminUsers] = useState( userContributors.map(user=>user.name));

```
Then need to do the same with:


```
{userContributors.map((item, index) => (
                    <MenuItem key={"aa" + item.id} value={item.name}>
                      {item.firstName}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
```

When you want to get the id/s you could use array.find function on the original array of objects to find the id's of each string name.